# devise invitable getting invalid token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm using Devise and Devise-invitable. However when I try to accept an invitation, it says the token is invalid. There's an issue with the new devise on how it saves the token...which I know is causing the issue (https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/402)

However, i'm not sure how to fix it still. The creator says use @token...but I have no idea how to get @token. Where does this variable come from? Here's what I have so far:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  private

  def invite_resource
    resource_class.invite!(email: params['user']['email'], company_id: current_user.company.id) do |u|
      # skip sending emails on invite
      u.invited_by_id      = current_user.id
      u.invited_by_type    = 'User'
      u.skip_invitation    = true
      u.invitation_sent_at = Time.now
    end
  end

  def accept_resource
    debugger
    resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)
  end
```

and the link I'm using:

```
= link_to 'Accept invitation', accept_invitation_url('user', :invitation_token => @token)
```

previously instead of @token I am using invitation.invitation_token but I guess that's not a hashed version? How do I insert the correct version into the above acceptance link?

Answer (score 0):

Your emails link looks fine as `@token` is generated by the mailer.  If you are like me you could have an invalid column type.  For example, on mine invitation_created_at was the wrong type, so I did a migration to change it to datetime:

```
class ChangeUsersInvitationCreatedAtToDatetime < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :invitation_created_at, :datetime
  end
end
```